# What are the differences between data and validated data?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

What transformations does Django Rest Framework make to data after validation? Does it only parse strings to `int` when possible?

Comment: Your title has a different question than your content. Which is what ?

Comment: Your question effectively comes down to "what is the difference between input and output?" - which is too broad

Comment: understanding transformations leads to know the difference in details, it's actually the same question

Comment: You should explain exactly what you mean by "data". Pretty much everything that happens in a computer can be called "data". Django and django rest framework will perform several steps of validation and data conversion.

Comment: I would like to point out that data and validated_data are specific to terms in the DRF serializer classes. If you read the question  by seeing data as meaning data argument provided to a DRF serializer, it would make more sense

Answer (score 23):

You can customize data in your `CommentSerializer.validate_content` method:

This is your serializer:

```py
class CommentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email=serializers.EmailField()
    content=serializers.CharField()
    def validate_content(self,value):
        #If content is 'baz' returns 'foo'
        if value and value == "baz":
            return "foo"
        return value
```

Let's try with wrong values (for email):

```py
>>> serializer = CommentSerializer(data={'email': 'foobar', 'content': 'baz'})

>>> serializer.data
Traceback (most recent call last):
    raise AssertionError(msg)
AssertionError: When a serializer is passed a `data` keyword  argument 
you must call `.is_valid()` before attempting to access the 
serialized `.data` representation.
```

You should either call `.is_valid()` first, or access `.initial_data` instead.

```py
>>> serializer.initial_data
{'content': 'baz', 'email': 'foobar'}

>>> serializer.validated_data
Traceback (most recent call last):
   raise AssertionError(msg) 
AssertionError: You must call `.is_valid()` before accessing `.validated_data`.

>>> serializer.is_valid()
False

>>> serializer.data
{'content': 'baz', 'email': 'foobar'}

>>> serializer.validated_data
{}

>>> serializer.errors
{'email': [u'Enter a valid email address.']}
```

Now Let's try with correct values

```py
>>> serializer2 = CommentSerializer(data={'email': 'foobar@email.it', 
'content': 'baz'})  
>>> serializer2.is_valid()
True

>>> serializer2.initial_data
{'content': 'baz', 'email': 'foobar@email.it'}
>>> serializer2.errors
{}

>>> serializer2.data
{'content': u'foo', 'email': u'foobar@email.it'}

>>> serializer2.validated_data
OrderedDict([(u'email', u'foobar@email.it'), (u'content', u'foo')])
```

So:

- `data` : is a dict and you can see it only after `is_valid()` (you can see only not validated values)
- `validated_data` is an `OrderedDict` and you can see it only after `is_valid()` and `is_valid() == True`

Comment: Why is content = foo when you try with correct values after calling is_valid() in the attribute data and validated_data?

Comment: Also, you said you can see only not validated values in the attribute data, but in the second example you are seeing the validated values.

Comment: What would be the default behavior of creating validated_data?

Answer (score 17):

`data` and `validated_data` **will not always be the same**.
For example:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
    phone = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_null=True)
```

We could get different data:

```
>>> user = UserSerializer(data={'name': 'Foo'})
>>> user.is_valid()
True
>>> user.data
{'name': 'Foo', 'phone': None}
>>> user.validated_data
{'name': 'Foo'}
```

Based on [`BaseSerializer` internal code](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L263-L264), `data` property is just `self.to_representation(self.validated_data)` whenever the serializer has been validated:

```
elif hasattr(self, '_validated_data') and not getattr(self, '_errors', None):
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.validated_data)
```

And in this case [`to_representation` internal code](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L526-L528) sets to `None` those cases.

---

Because of this behaviour I would recommend using `validated_data` over `data`. If you used `data` with a serializer like this, and explicitly sets attributes to an object based on `data`, you could set to `None` attributes that did not exist in initial data.

Answer (score 11):

**DESERIALIZING**

Data is the input to a Serializer
eg

`serializer = CommentSerializer(data={'email': 'foobar', 'content': 'baz'})`

As you can see email is invalid, so the following rule apply(from official docmentation)

> When deserializing data, you always need to call is_valid() before
> attempting to access the validated data, or save an object instance

```
serializer.is_valid()
```

If the `data` your trying to deserialize is valid `#True` then you can access the validated data as

```
serializer.validated_data
```

ADDITION

There is no data transformation after validation, it only check if your data is valid, if any validation errors occur, the `.errors` property will contain a dictionary representing the resulting error messages.

A good example is when your doing field validation

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    title = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    
    def validate_title(self, value):
        if 'django' not in value.lower():
           raise serializers.ValidationError("Title is not about Django")
        return value
```

`validate_title` will called each time you call `.is_valid()`, as you can see it only check if the title is django related, if `True` the value which in this case title is returned else `ValidationError` is raised. NO CHANGE OF DATA HERE

Comment: this doesn't answer the question. will data always look the same as validated data ?

Comment: do you have any official source that mention that there are no transformations ?

Comment: Check its implementation -> https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L221 @user2080105